# What was "carnal knowledge against the order of nature"?

Tags: legal-terms, common-law, legal-history, sexual-offences

S152(2), [Palestine Penal Code of 1936](https://learningpartnership.org/sites/default/files/resources/pdfs/Palestine-Penal-Code-Gaza-1936-English.pdf), makes reference to carnal knowledge against the order of nature:

> 152(2) Any person who:— (a) has carnal knowledge of any person against the order of nature; or (b) has carnal knowledge of an animal; or (c) permits a male person to have carnal knowledge of him or her against the order of nature, is guilty of a felony, and is liable to imprisonment for ten years.

At the time of enactment, [Mandatory Palestine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_Palestine) was a British protectorate, and ended its existence in 1948. But between 1936 and 1948, that law was in power as part of a common-law mandate country.

Does this term have a broader history of usage in the world of common law, and what does it mean?

Comment: As far as I am informed, Palestine uses "Islamic Law" aka Sharia as the basis of its law, **not** common law, at least according to the [Palestinian Basic Law, Art. 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_law#Articles_of_the_Basic_Law)

Comment: **also** the [Palestinian enal Coe of 1936](https://learningpartnership.org/sites/default/files/resources/pdfs/Palestine-Penal-Code-Gaza-1936-English.pdf) read: 151. For the purpose of this chapter any house, room or set 
of rooms in any house which is occupied or frequented by two,
or more females for the purpose of prostitution shall be deemed
to be a brothel.

Comment: You are interested in 152(2) Any person who:—
( a ) has carnal knowledge of any person against the order of
nature; or
(6) has carnal knowledge of an animal; or
(c) permits a male person to have carnal knowledge of him
or her against the order of nature,
is guilty of a felony, and is liable to imprisonment for ten years.

Comment: While the core question is very interesting to ask, you need to step up the game here and explain among others: When and where the legal code was in power, link to the text, put in the text of the article, explain why this is common law as the country is currently not common law **and** spell out the actual question **in the body of the question**.

Comment: Well, the term seems to originate in the British empire and find currency in commonwealth jurisdictions like Australia and India etc.

Comment: But I thought it was still in effect. I wasn’t aware that it isn’t any longer in effect much less when it might have ceased so being.

Comment: What is the law in Gaza seems to be a very complicated topic. But the phrase in question has a history independently of its current status in Gaza. Perhaps these are two (or more) separate questions.

Comment: @alexg yes, but you have very well encapsulated why it was that I chose to use  the common-law tag.

Comment: @Trish Thanks for the edit. The incomplete quotation mark was making my OCD instincts tingle.

Comment: @ohwilleke shall I tell you that they also were *different* quotation marks? ;)

Comment: Yeah I struggled to see why the title was highlighted in change diff/summary for a while before I noticed that there was a quirky quotation mark glyph going on.

Comment: @Seekinganswers "I struggled to see why the title was highlighted in change . . . " Just to be clear, stuff like that is no big deal in my book even though it is good to fix. Everybody does that sometimes and it doesn't reflect poorly on you.

Comment: @ohwilleke well thank you for reassuring me like that.

Answer (score 1):

> What was “carnal knowledge against the order of nature"?

Anal sex a.k.a. sodomy.

The phrase is widely used in places that have a common law tradition, see also, e.g. [this court ruling from Uganda](https://www.law.cornell.edu/women-and-justice/keyword/carnal_knowledge_against_the_order_of_nature) (a former British colony) in 2016.

The law review article, Hon. Michael Kirby AC CMG, "[THE SODOMY OFFENCE:  ENGLAND’S LEAST LOVELY CRIMINAL LAW EXPORT?](https://www.michaelkirby.com.au/images/stories/speeches/2000s/2011/2540-ARTICLE-JOURNAL-COMMONWEALTH-CRIMINAL-LAW.pdf)", Volume 1, JOURNAL OF COMMONWEALTH CRIMINAL LAW (2011), traces its history and dissemination into the British Colonies. The abstract of that article explains:

> This article describes the influence of the British Empire on the
> intercontinental spread of the criminal offences involving adult,
> private, consensual same-sex activity.  It describes the origins of
> the crimes in Judeo-Christian scriptures and early English common law
> and statutory offences.  The nineteenth century moves for criminal law
> codification in Europe succeeded in abolishing such offence.  They
> were not a feature of other European empires.  However, although
> codification of criminal law failed in England, five template codes
> exported the sodomy and other offences to every land ruled by Britain.
> In 41 of the 53 Commonwealth countries, the offences remain in force.
> The article describes how they were (often reluctantly) repealed by
> legislation between 1967-97 in the older dominions.  Repeal in newer
> Commonwealth countries has been slow or non-existent.  The author
> describes new developments that give hope for progress, including the
> Naz Foundation Case in India (2009) and the recent moves in the United
> Nations and elsewhere to foster legislative and judicial removal of
> this unlovely legacy of Empire.”

Comment: How did codification of criminal law fail in England when there was the buggery act? ( See http://enwp.org/Buggery_Act )

Comment: @Seekinganswers In England, initially statutes established only particular offenses which were in addition to the common law offenses. The criminal law of England was only comprehensively codified, with common law offenses abolished, much later, the 1800s if I recall correctly. But codification was present in the colonies sooner, where case law was a cumbersome way to transmit the whole body of substantive English criminal law.

Comment: I see… very interesting indeed. But what did you mean here by “substantive”?

Comment: @Seekinganswers in contrast to criminal procedure which is procedural rather than substantive criminal law. Substantive criminal law concerns what constitutes a crime and what penalties are authorized for those crimes, including substantive as opposed to procedural affirmative defenses.